# Show which check-boxes are checked on edit page

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

I have this edit page with a list of categories, which have a many-to-many relationship with posts. It looks like this:

[image]

I want to show which one are selected at the edit page. I have a solution with js, but want to know if it is possible with laravel.

[image]

The categories itself are populated from the database, so a user/admin can add more categories.

The controller is just like this:

```
    public function edit($id)
{
    $posts = Post::find($id);
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('post.edit', compact('posts', 'categories'));
}
```

and the view:

```
<div class="category section">
    <h4>Categories</h4>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <ul>
            @foreach( $categories as $category)
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="{{ $category->id }}" id="{{ $category->id }}">
                    <label for="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name}}</label>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
        <a href="/categories/create" target="_blank">Shto Kategori</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Relationships

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_post');
}
```

and

```
public function post(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'category_post');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $postCategories = [];

    $posts = Post::find($id);
    $postCategories = $posts->category->pluck('id')->toArray();

    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('post.edit', compact('posts', 'categories', 'postCategories'));
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach( $categories as $category)
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="{{ $category->id }}" id="{{ $category->id }}" {{ in_array($category->id, $postCategories) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
        <label for="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name}}</label>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Hope it helps.. Let me know if any problem with this answer..

Comment: Unfortunately i get > Call to a member function pluck() on null

Comment: got it fixed, I had to change the code on the controller just a bit, like this:
$postCategories = $posts->Category->pluck('id')->toArray();

Comment: assumed the relation name as `categories`, which is the laravel default.. Where you have the relation `category` this causes the error. I have updated the answer.